# How to check whether on left or right column ? (In a two-column document)

Tags: conditionals, multicol

In a two-columns document (or using the `multicol` package) : How do you check (for an "if-else" condition) if you are on the left or right **column** ?

I've searched everywhere and only found commands to check the parity of the *page*, not the ***column***...

Comment: as for pages you can not check at the time, you can save position using `\pdfsavepos` and check the x coordinate on the next run to see which column you are in

Comment: You can `\usepackage[colaction]{multicol}` and then `\docolaction{first column}{any middle column}{last column}`. Requires multiple LaTeX runs.

Comment: There is `\if@firstcolumn`, but I don't think it is reliable inside a paragraph near the bottom or top of the page.  The ifoddpage package doesn't help, unless you are at a page boundary.